# Is there a scenario where it makes sense to use NOT LIKE ANY?

Tags: sql, postgresql, teradata

When querying Teradata, I have been caught out using the `NOT LIKE ANY` keyword.
From parsing the keyword in plain English, I expected the query to return any values that were not like the values in the parameter list.

However, due to the boolean logic generated by the statement (i.e. `NOT LIKE X OR NOT LIKE Y`), all values in the table were returned.  The keyword I actually needed was `NOT LIKE ALL` (i.e. `NOT LIKE X AND NOT LIKE Y`).

[An example using Postgresql](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a6d6a/3):

```
CREATE TABLE t
    ("col" varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO t
    ("col")
VALUES
    ('Andrew'),
    ('Annie'),
    ('Bob'),
    ('Bowie'),
    ('Charles')
;

/* Returns 'Charles' */
select col
from t
where col not like all (array[ 'An%', 'Bo%' ])
;

/* Returns all values in table */
select col
from t
where col not like any (array[ 'An%', 'Bo%' ])
;
```

I understand the underlying logic behind why these results are being returned, but my question is are there any scenarios where it would make sense to use `NOT LIKE ANY`?

If not, is there a good reason for the database engine(s) to support this keyword, given the possibility for ambiguity based on the plain-English interpretation of the keyword?

Comment: You can do lots of stupid things in SQL :-) There's really no need for `NOT LIKE ANY`, but as the syntax allows negating any condition, it must be supported. Btw, most people (including myself) do have problems with boolean logic involving `NOT`

Comment: Yeah good point. I've done my fair share of stupid things myself. And I suppose I had considered that most of the keywords are designed for a specific purpose, rather than being built from components of boolean logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does make sense, with a slight modification.

Take this query:

```
SELECT g
FROM generate_series(9995, 10005) g
WHERE g::TEXT NOT LIKE ANY(ARRAY['9996','9997'])
```

If `g` is `NOT LIKE` *any* of them, it returns TRUE. The items of interest are numbers 9996 and 9997. The `NOT LIKE` comparison of 9996 against the first item in the array evaluates to FALSE because 9996 isn't `NOT LIKE` 9996. But we're looking for ANY matches, so we move on to the next one. 9996 is NOT LIKE 9997, so that evaluation is TRUE and 9996 is included. Same when 9997 is compared, except the first comparison returns TRUE. Therefore all numbers from generate_series are selected.

Now change it slightly:

```
SELECT g
FROM generate_series(9995, 10005) g
WHERE NOT g::TEXT LIKE ANY(ARRAY['9996','9997'])
```

Because the evaluation of ANY stops as soon as a comparison returns TRUE (I tried to find an official source for this but couldn't, however quite sure I read it before and it makes sense), when 9996 is compared against 9996 using `LIKE`, the `ANY` search is aborted because a match was found. This is then negated by `NOT`, and therefore 9996 is excluded from the result.

Similar story for 9997, except the first comparison isn't TRUE, so it continues to the next, which is, and that TRUE is then negated to become FALSE. The rest of the numbers don't match, so ANY returns FALSE, which is negated to TRUE.

The result if this query is all the number from generate_series except 9996 and 9997.

Incidentally, if the array had only one value then `g::TEXT NOT LIKE ANY([your array])` would return the expected result.

Comment: Hehe, trapped by boolean logic. :-) #1 translates to `g NOT LIKE 9996 OR g NOT LIKE 9997`, while #2 results in `g NOT LIKE 9996 AND g NOT LIKE 9997`

Comment: This is interesting. I guess I'd considered `NOT LIKE ANY` to be a keyword in its own right, rather than being composed of the `NOT`, `LIKE` and `ANY` keywords. I think I understand how it is evaluating the different values in the two examples above. Although that said, I'd still expect it to evaluate to `NOT (LIKE ANY (X, Y))` rather than `NOT LIKE (ANY (X, Y))`.

Comment: ... Although I'm still not sure I've got that right. Dnoeth has hit the nail on the head... Negative conditional logic is **confusing**

Comment: The `NOT g LIKE ANY(...)` can be also expressed as `g NOT LIKE ALL(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ANY` instead of `ALL`, you are not excluding any rows. Here `ANY` will act like `OR`. So in any scenarios you want to use `OR` for `IN` you can use `ANY` .

Better not use `ANY`, because we are making an equal to not equal.ie it is same as `IN`